# What is the equivalent of Mathematica's RegionPlot3D() in R?

Tags: r

I would like to generate a 3D plot that shows the 3D region representing a combination of inequalities. In Mathematica I use [`RegionPlot3D()`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionPlot3D.html):

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1 && x^2 + y^2 < z^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
  1}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 35, PlotRange -> All]
```

which generates:

[image]

How can I do that in R?

Comment: have a look at `?persp` as well as the `rgl` package

Comment: I like `persp` too, or you could investigate `plot3D`

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt How can my answer be improved?

Answer (score 0):

This makes the plot:

```
#equivalent to range and plotpoints
x <- seq(-1, 1, by=0.01)
y <- seq(-1, 1, by=0.01)
z <- seq(-1, 1, by=0.01)

df <- setNames(expand.grid(x, y, z), c("x", "y", "z"))
df <- transform(df, ueq = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1) & (x^2 + y^2 < z^2))
df$color <- ifelse(df$ueq == TRUE, "green" , "red")

#use this rgl
require(rgl)
with(df[df$ueq == TRUE, ], plot3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, col=color, type="p", size=5))
grid3d(c("x", "y+", "z"))
```